# Reading Chat Threads in MS Teams via REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When can we expect the MS Graph API for Teams to support reading Chat Threads in MS Teams via REST API?

The Beta release, published in 2017, hints that this functionality is coming soon.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/chatthread

In the Microsoft Teams July 2018 Community Call, I heard a guidance that Graph API for Teams will reach GA around 2018 Ignite (end of September).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGsBvx7bAwQ

Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

The /beta version of APIs to read channel messages is already available. Please have a look at [messages API documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/chatmessage).

Comment: He's not asking a programming question, he's asking about the existence of an API. The only possible response is a link to the documentation for that API. What else would answer the question? Clearly the right answer isn't to copy/paste from the docs.

Comment: I was inquiring about reading chat threads and not chat messages. According to the beta API, reading chat threads is not supported at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't the right forum for such questions because this isn't a programming problem, but I'll answer anyway. You've seen the link to the API docs, so that's the answer to that question.

Still on track for moving certain APIs to 1.0 by Ignite. (Haven't announced which ones, but they are the ones that have been in beta the longest.)

Comment: "Answer well-asked questions
Not all questions can or should be answered here." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I had surfaced this issue previously in the Microsoft Tech Community Teams forum - but that thread wasn't getting much traction.